# Using a variable in an Azure pipeline

Tags: azure-pipelines

```yaml
name: $(Build.BuildId)-${{ variables['Build.SourceBranchName']}}

- ${{ if not(or(eq(variables['Build.SourceBranchName'], 'master'), eq(variables['Build.SourceBranchName'], 'main'))) }}:
  - task: Npm@1
    displayName: 'npm version' 
    inputs:
      workingDir: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/Thingamajig'
      command: custom
      customCommand: version prerelease --preid=$(name)
```

But

```
npm verb stack Error: Invalid version: "0.0.1-$(name).0"
```

Can it be made to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`name` is used to customize run number in the YAML pipeline. If you want to consume it, you can use `$(Build.BuildNumber)`.

See the detailed info from [Configure run or build numbers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/run-number?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml).

Comment: That works; thank you. (I'd never have guessed that the value was acutally in a vaiable with a different name -- Azure pipeline YML is so obscure.)

Comment: `name` is a [property of the pipeline](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/yaml-schema/pipeline?view=azure-pipelines#properties) and isn't a [predefined variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#build-variables-devops-services). `Build.BuildNumber` is the predefined variable and is name of the completed build.